# Dagger2 Component as Static Global Variable

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-2

My Android app has multiple activities. The MainActivity constructs a Dagger2 component in its onCreate() method and assigns it to a static variable so any class can call the static method MainActivity.getDaggerComponent() to then inject itself with dependencies.

The problem I'm discovering is that when I start up my VideoPlayerActivity, the MainActivity object sometimes gets its onPause() invoked. If this happens, the static component variable gets set to null. At a later point, VideoPlayerActivity needs to inject its dependencies, but there is no component so things blow up.

How does one ensure that a Dagger2 component is available at all times for all activities?

Comment: Initialize it in `Application` class or just statically

Comment: I need a reference to the MainActivity to pass into the component's constructor, so I don't think either of these methods would work. If I didn't have to, those would be perfect.

Comment: Then it might be that you're doing a very wrong thing trying to use dependencies of one `Activity` in another `Activity`. This might create memory leaks and in particular sounds like a design problem. Can you please provide more details on what you actually trying to solve with Dependency Injection?

Comment: I think you're correct, but I'm not sure how to solve this. For an example of what I'm doing, I want to use one OkHttpClient across my entire program. Using multiple OkHttpClients can slow things down dramatically, so I want to share this across all classes that make requests.

Comment: But there is no need to use `Activity` reference for that, right?

Comment: That was just for an example. I use the activity for different things. But I took your suggestion of initializing in the Application which seems to have helped things. It doesn't appear that you can guarantee an Activity's static variables will stick around, so Application-level is the way to go. If you put your response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize Dagger component in `Application` class or just statically. It might be that you're doing a very wrong thing trying to use dependencies of one Activity in another Activity. This might create memory leaks and in particular sounds like a design problem. What if your first `Activity` was already destroyed? Who will free up the Dagger instance? Why graph belongs to first `Activity` and not to the second one? What if user will enter your app from the second `Activity` - then first one won't be even initialized. And so on, and so on.

If you still need `Activity` instance, then you should use `Activity` specific component within the `Activity` and move everything else in global (`Application` wide) component.